# Gitlab-CI: conditional variables?

Tags: gitlab-ci

In our gitlab-ci file we have some variables like this:

```
variables:
  ...
  LOCAL_IMAGE_PHP: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/php:$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
  ...
```

Which we use as the image file for another stage:

```
.build-php:
  ...
  image: $LOCAL_IMAGE_PHP
  ...
```

We then have a docker image with tag `master`, `staging` and `develop`. So the correct image is automatically chosen based on which branch is currently getting build.

However, we also want to use this to build and run automatic tests on our feature branches. However, no `php:feature/something` images exist.

Is it possible to conditionally assign another variable based on the value of `$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH`? Something like `DOCKER_TAG: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH if ($CI_COMMIT_BRANCH in ['master', 'staging', 'develop']) else 'develop'`. So `DOCKER_TAG` would fallback to `develop` if it's an a feature branch.

So in a way it should select the corresponding docker image on the branches `master`, `staging` and `develop`, but fallback to `develop` on any other branch.

Is something like that possible? Or is there a different way to handle this kind of scenario?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you somehow solve the issue?